# How instantiate a view model with constructor parameters using Caliburn Micro's IOC?

Tags: inversion-of-control, ioc-container, caliburn.micro

In my bootstrapper file, I want to display the root view for my view model, ONH836ViewModel.  This view model derives from BaseViewModel, which has a single constructor with five parameters:

```
public BaseViewModel(IExportedDataMonitor monitor, IGasLabWorklistService worklistService, IRawDataConduit rawDataConduit,
            ISettingService settingService, IDataReportingService dataReportingService)
```

Here is the pertinent code from the bootstrapper:

```
class AppInitializer : BootstrapperBase
    {
        SimpleContainer container = new SimpleContainer();

        public AppInitializer()
        {
            Start();
        }
        protected override void OnStartup(object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(sender, e);
            DisplayRootViewFor<ONH836ViewModel>();
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {           
            container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IExportedDataMonitor), null, typeof(FakeExportedDataMonitor));
            container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IGasLabWorklistService), null, typeof(FakeGasLabWorklistService));
            container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IRawDataConduit), null, typeof(FakeRawDataConduit));
            container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ISettingService), null, typeof(FakeSettingService));
            container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IDataReportingService), null, typeof(FakeDataReportingService));

            container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(BaseViewModel), null, typeof(ONH836ViewModel));

        }
```

The OnStartup method throws a NullReferenceException on the DisplayRootView line. I assume this happens because I am doing something wrong in the Configure method.  Can someone identify and correct my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start() should be Initialize() for one, assuming v2.xx of CM.  save yourself some typing referring to the following code.

`container.Singleton<ONH836ViewModel>();`

for your interfaces I would suggest

`container.Instance<IExportedDataMonitor>(new FakeExportDataMonitor());`

and they can be chained...

`container.Instance<IGasLabWorkListService>(new FakeGasLabWorklistService())
            .Instance<IRawDataConduit>(new FakeRawDataConduit())
            .Instance<ISettingService>(new FakeSettingService());`

more than likely the reason for NullReference was due to Configure never being called due to Initialize() not being called in the Constructor.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the chaining capability; thanks for the insight.  The problem wasn't that Configure wasn't being called (it was), but that the Null Reference was occurring in an overridden GetInstance method.  I'm not sure what I was doing wrong in it, but when I commented it out, the Null Reference went away.